# How to loop over response object with nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This is my response. that i am getting

```
{status: 'Success', length: 7, data: {…}}
```

This is an expanded version.

```
data:
tours: (7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 7
status: "Success"
```

I wanted to loop over the tour property but doing a map is not going to work. I tried doing Object.entries() to convert it into an array but it is also not working. Can anyone suggest me a solution?

```
export const getData = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch(isLoading(true));
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5555/api/bc1/tours`);

      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error while connecting with server`);
      }

      const data = await res.json();
      dispatch(isLoading(false));
      dispatch(getTours(data));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(
        checkStatus({
          title: `Error`,
          message: error.message,
        })
      );
    }
  };
};
```

getTours is an empty array.

calling it in app.js

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getData());
  }, [dispatch]);
```

Comment: `response.data.tours.map(...)` or `response.data.tours.forEach(...)`

Comment: @SimoneRossaini No this will not work I have tried this many times before asking this question

Comment: Can't tell what your response actually is, so can't provide any hints as to how to access specific parts.

Comment: then there is another problem, because these must work.

Comment: Can you please include a [mcve] showing what you have tried so far, as well as in what way it is failing to work?  This would be the expected level of detail in a question as spelled out in the [ask] guidelines.  Without that context, it will be difficult to give you direction specific to the issue you are facing.

Comment: @AlexanderNied please check the edited question

Comment: @aishasharma That's still not a [mcve]. Where is that data logged? How are you calling `getData()`?

Comment: @Ivar check the edit and using in component by useSelector to get access

Answer (score 2):

No need to convert tours to object. You can do this:

```
const result = {status: 'Success', length: 7, data: {…}};
result.data.tours.map(function(item, i){
  // your code
})
```